# How to force page display without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

Major web sites (e.g. Google Groups) now refuse to display any content unless your browser has JavaScript enabled. Some ultra-light browsers like [w3m](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m) and [Dillo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dillo) don't support JavaScript.

What strategies could these browsers incorporate to force display of JavaScript-only web sites?

**Edit:** To prevent a flood of irrelevant replies, I will point out that what I'm asking for *is* possible and has been done. [NetSurf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetSurf) does a good job of it, while [Dillo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dillo) does it though very badly.

I'm asking for the best way(s) to add this functionality to an ultra-light browser.

Comment: Start supporting JavaScript? It is either that or you go to webapp authors and beg them to make static version.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could ask this question - if a site requires javascript, the browser must as well for it to even work...

Answer (score 4):

If a site decides to not display any content without the use of javascript, there is nothing a browser without javascript can do to change that.

If, the content simply isn't there until it's retrieved and rendered via javascript, there just isn't anything a non-javascript browser can do to get around that.

The only alternatives are to beg the site's author to make a version of their site that works via plain HTML and doesn't rely on javascript or to get a browser that supports javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Implement JavaScript support

Option 2: On a case-by-case basis, re-implement all the essential functionality that the site uses JavaScript for (and keep it up to date with changes).